# Using subscript in a string

Tags: string-manipulation, custom-notation

I am trying to create a string of the form

$0 < d_1 < d_2 < \ldots < d_n$

For a given n.

My closest attempt so far is

```
eqn[n_] :=
  For[i = 1; str = "0", i <= n, i++, 
   str = str <> "<" <> ToString[Subscript[d, i]]];
```

But for, say n=6, this gives me

```
"0<d
 1<d
 2<d
 3<d
 4<d
 5<d
 6"
```

Where it seems to have interpreted the string as `"0<d\n 1<d\n 2<d\n 3<d\n 4<d\n 5<d\n 6"`.

Why is it doing this? How can I achieve the result I am looking for?

Comment: Use `ToString[..., StandardForm]`.

Comment: If you just need this for display purposes, you can also use `StringForm`

Answer (score 6):

Probably best to use something like `Fold` and get used to functional style

```
eqn[n_] := TraditionalForm[Fold[#1 <> " < " <> 
     ToString[Subscript[d, #2], StandardForm] &, "0", Range[n]]]
```

[image]

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom  The first use of `ToString` is unnecessary actually. I'll make an edit

Comment: Okido, +1 and deleting my comment :).

Answer (score 5):

Here's my entry:

```
string[n_] := ToString[0 < ## & @@ Array[Subscript[d, #] &, n], StandardForm]

string[7]
```

[image]

This assumes that none of the `Subscript[d, _]` expressions are assigned.

Here is a different method converting to strings as early as possible, using the single-argument form of `Subscript`:

```
string2[n_] := "0" <> Array[" < d" <> ToString[Subscript@#, StandardForm] &, n]
```

The spacing is a bit wider with this one.  You could use narrower spaces, e.g.:

```
string2[n_] := 
  "0"<>Array["\[MediumSpace]<\[MediumSpace]d"<>ToString[Subscript@#,StandardForm]&, n]
```

One more, quite concise:

```
string3[n_] := "0" <> Array[" < \!\(d\_" <> ToString@# <> "\)" &, n]
```

Answer (score 3):

Most important thing is what b.gatessucks has said. This answer is just a variation of the method:

```
eq[0] = "0";
eq[n_] :="0 < " <> StringJoin @@ 
               Riffle[ToString[Subscript[d, #], StandardForm] & /@ Range[n], " < "]
```

If you do not need string but an expression which looks like this, then it is good to remember `Row`'s 2nd argument:

```
Row[{"0"}~Join~(ToString[Subscript[d, #], StandardForm] & /@ Range[4]), " < "]
```