# StringReplace adds "~~" to words with Tooltip

Tags: string-manipulation, tooltip

I'm adding tooltip to certain words in a text. I guess since words with tooltips are not considered as strings, it gives the `~~` operators before and after the word in the result. Needless to say, I don't need them in the result. I have a huge text and thousands of words so looking for a fast-running operation. Thanks

```
txt = "Good, better, best. Never let it rest. 'Til your good is
better and your better is best.";
words = {"good", "better", "best"};
tooltips = {"good2", "better2", "best2"};
sw = {words, tooltips}\[Transpose];
wordsWithTooltips = Tooltip[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ sw;
tls = {words, wordsWithTooltips}\[Transpose];
StringReplace[txt, #[[1]] -> #[[2]] & /@ tls]
```

Result:

> Good, ~~better~~, ~~best~~. Never let it rest. 'Til your ~~good~~ is ~~better~~ and your ~~better~~ is ~~best~~.

---

Side question; note that first word (Good) didn't get a tooltip since it starts with a capital letter. How can I set `IgnoreCase` to `True` in this type of setting?

Comment: Out of curiosity: do you want to annotate certain words just for visualization purposes or do you intend to tag the string for some data mining / machine learning task?

Comment: This particular one is for visualization purposes. Helping students with archaic words.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I prefer avoiding `TraditionalForm` strings, e.g.,

```
ToString[Tooltip[x/y,stuff],TraditionalForm]//FullForm
(* "\!\(\*FormBox[TagBox[TooltipBox[FractionBox[\"x\", \"y\"], \"stuff\"], 
Function[Annotation[Slot[1], stuff, \"Tooltip\"]]], TraditionalForm]\)" *)
```

Instead, I would use `StringForm`. The simplest version would be:

```
indices = {"`1`", "`2`", "`3`"};
StringForm[
    StringReplace[txt, Thread[Rule[words, indices]]],
    Sequence @@ Thread[Tooltip[words, tooltips]]
]
(* StringForm["Good, `2`, `3`. Never let it rest. 'Til your `1` is `2` and your 
`2` is `3`.", Tooltip["good", "good2"], Tooltip["better", "better2"],
Tooltip["best", "best2"]] *)
```

However, you wanted to use `IgnoreCase`. The `Tooltip` will have to be different for different cases, and a priori, you don't know how many versions with different cases there will be. So, the indices will have to be generated dynamically as the string is processed. To do this, I introduce a helper function:

```
toIndex[word_] := toIndex[word] = CompoundExpression[
    Sow[ToLowerCase[word] /. Thread[Rule[words, tooltips]], word],
    "`"<>ToString[i++]<>"`"
]
```

Then, I use this helper function to convert words into their indexed form:

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[{i=1, toIndex},
    Apply[
        StringForm[#1, Sequence@@#2]&,
        Reap[
            StringReplace[txt, x:Alternatives@@words :> toIndex[x], IgnoreCase->True],
            _String,
            Tooltip[#1, #2[[1]]]&
        ]
    ]
]
(* StringForm["`1`, `2`, `3`. Never let it rest. 'Til your `4` is `2` and your
`2` is `3`.", Tooltip["Good", "good2"], Tooltip["better", "better2"],
Tooltip["best", "best2"], Tooltip["good", "good2"]] *)
```

Comment: One might also choose to use `StringTemplate[]` instead of `StringForm[]`; this route requires a preliminary `ToString[Tooltip[(* stuff *)], StandardForm]`, tho.

Answer (score 10):

This is because the elements of `wordsWithTooltips` aren't strings. If you convert to strings, there's no issue.

```
StringReplace[txt, #1 -> ToString[#2, TraditionalForm] & @@@ tls]
```

[image: gif]

Comment: I noticed that this only works when specifying a _form_ with `ToString`, such as `TraditionalForm` or `StandardForm`.

Comment: @Sascha Yes, that's because the default is `OutputForm` which is no good here.

Answer (score 3):

This question is closely related to:

- [How to 'merge' a list like FromDigits, but with a mixture of numbers and symbols?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20412/121)
- [Using subscript in a string](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29042/121)

As Chip Hurst already explained your [`Tooltip`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tooltip.html) expressions need to be converted to strings if they are to be appended as strings.  You could also display the expression as a [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row.html) instead:

```
Row@*List @@ StringReplace[txt, Rule @@@ tls]
```

If *that* expression needs to be converted to a string it can be done en masse:

```
ToString[%, StandardForm];
% // Head
```

> ```
> String
> ```